# Is it possible to highlight part of a rowspan column?

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML table that looks something like this:
[image]

```
<table>
 <thead>
 <tr>
 <th>no.</th>
 <th>name</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
 <tbody id="list">
<tr>
<td class="group" id="group_1" rowspan="3">1</td>
<td id="name_1">amy</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="name_1">test</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="name_1">amy2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="group" id="group_2">2</td>
<td id="name_2">water</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

```
function highlightKeyword() {
        let searchWord = document.getElementById("search").value.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '');
        let rows = document.getElementById("list").getElementsByTagName("tr");

        for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            let targetName = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td").length - 1];
            let name = targetName.textContent.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '');
            let targetCode = targetName['id'].substr(5);
            let groupTd = document.getElementById(`group_${targetCode}`);

            if (searchWord != "") { 
                if (name.includes(searchWord)) { 
                    rows[i].classList.add("highlighted-row");
                    groupTd.classList.add("highlighted-row");
                } else {
                    rows[i].classList.remove("highlighted-row");
                    groupTd.classList.remove("highlighted-row");
                }
            } else {
                rows[i].classList.remove("highlighted-row");
                groupTd.classList.remove("highlighted-row");
            }
        }
    }
```

Finds words matching the search bar within an array where the table head is a name.
When I find a matching 'td', I want to find the corresponding row and set the background color.
so,  I want something like this:
[image]

What's the easiest way for me to achieve this?

Thanks

[image]

.

```js
function highlightKeyword() {
        let searchWord = document.getElementById("search").value.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '');
        let rows = document.getElementById("list").getElementsByTagName("tr");

        for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            let targetName = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td").length - 1];
            let name = targetName.textContent.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '');
            let targetCode = targetName['id'].substr(5);
            let groupTd = document.getElementById(`group_${targetCode}`);

            if (searchWord != "") { 
                if (name.includes(searchWord)) {
                    rows[i].classList.add("highlighted-row");
                    groupTd.classList.add("highlighted-row");
                } else {
                    rows[i].classList.remove("highlighted-row");
                    groupTd.classList.remove("highlighted-row");
                }
            } else {
                rows[i].classList.remove("highlighted-row");
                groupTd.classList.remove("highlighted-row");
            }
        }
    }
```

```css
.highlighted-row {
       background-color: yellow;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control w-30" id="search" oninput="highlightKeyword()">
<table class="table table-sm table-bordered">
<table class="table table-sm table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>group.</th>
        <th>name</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="list">

    <tr>
        <td class="group" id="group_1" rowspan="3">1</td>
        <td id="name_1">amy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="name_1">test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="name_1">amy2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="group" id="group_2">2</td>
        <td id="name_2">water</td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following way:

```html
<style>
    .highlighted-row {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
</style>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>no.</th>
            <th>name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="list">
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3">1</td>
            <td>amy</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>amy2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>water</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<input type="text" id="search" oninput="highlightKeyword()" placeholder="Search...">

<script>
    function highlightKeyword() {
        //get the search input, remove whitespaces, and convert to lowercase
        let searchWord = document.getElementById("search").value.trim().toLowerCase();
        //get all rows in the tbody
        let rows = document.getElementById("list").getElementsByTagName("tr");

        for (let row of rows) {
            //get the name from the last cell of the current row
            let name = row.lastElementChild.textContent.toLowerCase();
            //check if there is a match between the name and the search input
            let isMatch = name.includes(searchWord);

            //toggle the class if there is a match and the search inpt is not blank
            row.classList.toggle("highlighted-row", isMatch && searchWord !== "");
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Search with Individual Span Element Highlighting:**

```html
<style>
    .highlighted-substring {
        background-color: yellow;
        display: inline-block;
    }
</style>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>no.</th>
            <th>name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="list">
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3">1</td>
            <td>amy</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>amy2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>water</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<input type="text" id="search" oninput="highlightKeyword()" placeholder="Search...">

<script>
    function highlightKeyword() {
        // get the search input, remove whitespaces, and convert to lowercase
        let searchWord = document.getElementById("search").value.trim().toLowerCase();
        // get all rows in the tbody
        let rows = document.getElementById("list").getElementsByTagName("tr");

        for (let row of rows) {
            // get the name from the last cell of the current row
            let nameCell = row.lastElementChild;
            let name = nameCell.textContent.toLowerCase();

            // clear existing HTML to reset highlighting
            nameCell.innerHTML = "";

            // iterate through the name to find the substring match
            let index = name.indexOf(searchWord);
            if (index !== -1) {
                // create a span element for the matched substring
                let beforeText = name.substring(0, index);
                let matchedText = name.substring(index, index + searchWord.length);
                let afterText = name.substring(index + searchWord.length);

                let beforeElement = document.createTextNode(beforeText);
                let matchedElement = document.createElement("span");
                matchedElement.textContent = matchedText;
                matchedElement.classList.add("highlighted-substring");
                let afterElement = document.createTextNode(afterText);

                // append elements to the name cell
                nameCell.appendChild(beforeElement);
                nameCell.appendChild(matchedElement);
                nameCell.appendChild(afterElement);
            } else {
                // if no match, append the entire name
                nameCell.textContent = name;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. But what I want is when I input 't', <td class="group" id="group_1" rowspan="3">1</td>
 I want this part to be colored by adding a class tag.
I modified the code slightly to use the tag value.

Comment: @mentha, added another solution please check.